# Overwrite NginX config for subdirectory

Tags: nginx, subdirectory

I'd like to install a software in a subdirectory of an NginX Vhost.

Currently I've got:

```
    server {
        server_name www.website.com;
        root /var/www/website.com/www.website.com/;
        gzip_static on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/website.com_access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/website.com_error.log;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
                allow 192.168.0.0/16;
                deny all;
        }

        location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
                return 403;
        }

        location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
                return 403;
        }

        location ~ (^|/)\. {
                return 403;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location @rewrite {
                rewrite ^ /index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 150;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        }

        location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ {
                try_files $uri @rewrite;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                log_not_found off;
        }
}
```

Now for the subdirectory I tried:

```
    location /mseiten/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /mseiten/index.php?q=$request_uri;
            allow all;
            root /var/www/website.com/www.website.com;
    }
```

But all I'm seeing is a 403 if I try to access /mseiten/ in my browser (it should direct me to my installation wizard). I've uncommented all rules that `return 403;` but with the same results.
Would it be possible to setup sth. like a clean slate for a sub directory?

Comment: Remove `$uri/` from `try_files`

Comment: Ok .. then I receive a 500 in the browser and the error log says:
`rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/mseiten/"`